# Ein hinter-verschlossenen-Türen-geplantes Spiel

Tags: single-word-request

Ich suche nach einem Wort oder einer Redewendung, die folgendes Szenario bezeichnet:

Zwei (oder mehr, und nicht unbedingt politische) Parteien vereinbaren   miteinander hinter verschlossenen Türen, der Öffentlichkeit ein "unerwünschtes Ereignis" vorzugaukeln. Dadurch profitieren beide Parteien.

Zum Beispiel schickt eine Sängerin einem Hacker ihre Nacktbilder, und der Hacker veröffentlicht diese Bilder vereinbarterweise, aber das Publikum glaubt, dass es eine Enthüllung ist. Das steigert die Popularität der Sängerin und auch des Hacker (in dessen dunkler Welt).

Da ich kein konkretes Wort zur Hand habe, konnte ich nicht in einem Wörterbuch nachschlagen.

Comment: I'll sit back and watch whether someone can come up with a single word describing the whole plot of a thriller ;)

Comment: Verschwörung???

Comment: @tofro in meiner Muttersprache gibt es eine Redewendung dafür:) Bisher habe ich gesehen, dass es noch mehr spezifische Wörter im Deutschen gibt. Deswegen bin ich mir ganz sicher, dass es etwas gibt..

Comment: Wie heißt denn das Wort in Deiner Muttersprache?

Comment: @IQV Nö, die Verschwörung ist was die Leute behaupten. Die Verschwörung kann wahr oder unwahr sein. Das passt nicht ganz genau.

Comment: [Konspiration](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konspiration)?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann wenn man wörtlich übersetzt, ist es *ein geplanter Kampf*

Comment: Verschwörung: Nein, nein. Die Verschwörung ist etwas Reales. Mit "Verschwörungstheorie" jedoch versucht der Sprecher auszudrücken, dass er die Verschwörung für nur behauptet hält.

Comment: @IQV Du hattest recht. Ich habe *Verschwörung* mit *Verschörungstheorie* verwechselt. Nachdem ich die Bedeutung gelesen habe, denke ich jetzt, dass "Verschwörung" die richtige Antwort sein kann.

Comment: @Ad Infinitum: "Verschwörung" ist halt ein bisschen zu stark für das (kleine) Szenario, das du beschrieben hast. Bei "Verschwörung"  geht es meistens um etwas größeres - den Sturz einer Regierung o.ä. Insofern ist das "abgekartete Spiel", auf das andere dann noch kamen, sicherlich der passendste Ausdruck.

Comment: @Christian Geiselmann Hmm. Dann kann man sagen, ein Komplott ist auch für ein kleine Szenario (wie mein Bespiel), wenn eine Verschörung immer für die grösseren Ereignisse geeignet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Der Vorschlag

> abgekartetes Spiel

trifft das Szenario ganz gut. Laut [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/abgekartet) bedeutet die Redewendung "heimlich vereinbart, regelwidrig zum Nachteil eines Dritten abgesprochen". Das passt sehr gut zu dem Beispiel, dass zwei Personen etwas geheim verabreden und die Öffentlichkeit an die große Enthüllung glaubt.

Eine andere Möglichkeit ist

> Verschwörung

Laut [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verschw%C3%B6rung) bedeutete das Wort ursprünglich "die Verbindung von Personen durch Schwur zu etwas Üblem oder was als Übel angesehen wird gegen eine Obergewalt". Damit verwandt ist

> Konspiration

das "die Zusammenarbeit mehrerer Personen unter einheitlicher Zielsetzung und bewusster Ausschaltung fremden oder öffentlichen Einblicks“ ist", was dem genannten Beispiel auch sehr nahe kommt. Die Verbindung aus "Verschwörung" und "Konspiration" ist dann schließlich ein

> Komplott.

Welche der Möglichkeiten am besten passt, muss im Kontext gesehen und entschieden werden.

Answer (score 5):

**Mauschelei**

Der Duden definiert das dazugehörige Verb *[mauscheln](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/mauscheln#b2-Bedeutung-1)* als

> (umgangssprachlich abwertend) unter der Hand in undurchsichtiger Weise Vorteile aushandeln, begünstigende Vereinbarungen treffen, Geschäfte machen

Comment: eine sehr gute Empfehlung. Danke schön. Ich habe das Wort auch recherchiert. Ein anderes Wörterbuch (http://www.ruhrgebietssprache.de/lexikon/mauscheln.html) sagt;

Comment: (auch: "rummauscheln", "zusammenmauscheln") korruptes Verhalten, etwas zum eigenen Vorteil hindrehen, verändern; handeln am Rande der Legalität oder darüber; "Mauschelei" - Übervorteilung; oft zu Gunsten von Honoratioren oder deren Kindern ("Die Laumänner von dat Bauamt ham sich verdorri da widder wat zusammengemauschelt.")

Answer (score 4):

Nach meiner Recherche habe ich was gefunden aber vieleicht gibt es eine passendere Redewendung oder Wort dafür.

> ein abgekartetes Spiel

Die Bedeutung ist;

> Manipulation durch heimliche Absprachen.
>
> Abkarten heißt ursprünglich, beim Mischen und Ausgeben der Spielkarten diese einzusehen und das Spiel zu manipulieren

Beispielsatz;

> Entweder verfügen die Politiker über einen sehr geringen
> Sachverstand, wenn es um ökonomische Zusammenhänge geht, oder sie und
> die Banken treiben ein abgekartetes Spiel.

[Souce](http://www.phraseo.de/phrase/ein-abgekartetes-spiel/)

Comment: Ja, nur dass das normalerweise für mindestens eine Person negativ ist.

Comment: @Em1 Das kann sein. Die Parteien, die heimlich mitplanen, profitieren. In dem Beispielsatz;  *Die Banken treiben ein abgekartetes Spiel*. Von diesem Tat machen sie gewinn, wahrend andere Geld verlieren.

Comment: Richtig, deine Anforderung war ja nur, dass die beteiligten Parteien ihren Vorteil daraus ziehen. Und nicht, dass niemand benachteiligt wäre.

Answer (score 3):

Man könnte es vielleicht

> ein Komplott

nennen. Allerdings ist das Wort ein bisschen aus der Mode. Im 19. Jahrhundert war es aber in den Zeitungen des öfteren zu lesen, vor allem bezogen auf ein "Mordkomplott" gegen Regierungsmitglieder o.ä.

Zu überlegen wäre, ob vielleicht auch

> ein Plot

geht. Das Wort, ursprünglich aus dem Englischen kommend, wo es zunächst ein Stück Land bezeichnete, ist heute eingebürgert (z.B. auch in das Duden-Universalwörterbuch der Deutschen Sprache, Ausgabe 1989, hier zunächst noch als *"Handlung einer epischen oder dramatischen Dichtung, eines Films o.ä."*), aber in metonymischer Verwendung könnte man es auch für so

> ein Mauschelspiel

wie es in der Eingangsfrage beschrieben ist, gebrauchen.

Sicher ist, dass deine Sängerin und dein Hacker die Öffentlichkeit

> hinters Licht führen

oder wenigstens

> an der Nase herumführen

wollen. Ob sich das Publikum allerdings in der Tat

> für dumm verkaufen

und sich

> einen Bären aufbinden

oder

> ein X für ein U vormachen

lässt, ist eine andere Frage. Denn eine aufmerksame Öffentlichkeit wird natürlich

> den Braten riechen

und darum nicht

> in die Falle tappen.

(Die letzten Ausdrücke sind etwas breiter, nicht speziell für "zwei Parteien sprechen sich ab, eine dritte hinters Licht zu führen", aber der Situation verwandt sind sie allemal.)

Comment: Lustigerweise verweist Wikipedia bei dem Begriff "Komplott" auf "Verschwörung" oder "Intrige".

Comment: Danke sehr. Ich wusste nicht, dass es so viele Begriffe gibt. Unter Anderem werde ich bestimmt *für dumm verkaufen* gebrauchen :)

Answer (score 1):

Ein

> [Klüngel](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Kluengel)

ist eine Gruppe von Personen, die sich gegenseitig Vorteile verschaffen. Daher wäre

> [Klüngelei](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Kluengelei)

nicht ganz fehl am Platz.

Ebenso passt die

> [Kumpanei](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Kumpanei)

einigermaßen zum genannten Beispiel, laut Wiktionary die *»verdeckte Zusammenarbeit unter Verletzung von anerkannten Regeln oder Gesetzen«*.

Die Ausdrücke

> - fingierte Aktion
> - [bewusste] Irreführung der Öffentlichkeit

lassen den Täuschungscharakter besonders hervortreten. Allerdings braucht man hier keinen Partner, man kann es auch allein. Das zugrunde liegende Verb [fingieren](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/fingieren) definiert sich als *»in einer bestimmten Absicht vortäuschen, vorspiegeln; erdichten«*, während [irreführen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/irrefuehren) als *»[absichtlich] einen falschen Eindruck entstehen lassen; zu einer falschen Annahme verleiten, täuschen«* beschrieben wird.

Comment: Sehr gut. *fingierte Aktion*. Aber es ist nicht klar (und unwichtig), ob es eine oder mehrere Personen in einer fingierte Aktion beteiligt sind?

Comment: @AdInfinitum: Stimmt, habe die Antwort aktualisiert.